# How to decrypt with EC on API 28?

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

How can I decrypt a byte[] with Cipher using EC algorithm on apps targeting API 28?

I can't use another securit provider. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html and EC isn't supported by Cipher.https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/javax/crypto/Cipher?hl=en.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify any *protocol* or *algorithm*, only a *primitive* (EC), we cannot say how you can decrypt a *specific* byte array, because we don't know how it was encrypted. However, you can implement ECIES by using ECDH key agreement and a symmetric cipher. Both of those should be present.

If you can figure out how to create a cryptographic provider for the JCA then you might even implement `CipherSpi` and use `Cipher` for your specific algorithm (by creating a `"MyECIES"` service). But note that this may not be for the uninitiated in Java JCA / cryptography.